# How to print the result of an association table

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have a user and a branch table and it has many to many relationship.Hence i have defined and association table.

```
user_branch_map = db.Table(
    'user_branch_map',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('branch_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('branch.id'), primary_key=True)
    )
```

the user_branch_map table has following contents :

```
#   user_id branch_id
1   3   1
2   1   2
3   1   1
4   1   3
5   1   4
```

How can i print out the result of user_branch_map not the ids but the join result of user and branch table.i am able to print the branch table info but i also need user info . i have tried these following ways :

```
def get(self):
    # maptable= User.query.join(user_branch_map).join(Branch). \
    # filter((user_branch_map.c.user_id == User.id) & (user_branch_map.c.branch_id == Branch.id)).all()
    # print(type(maptable))
    # # maptable = db.session.query(user_branch_map).join(User).all()
    # # print(maptable)
    # for row in maptable:
    #     print(row)


    # branches = db.session.query(Branch).all()
    # q = db.session.query(User).options(eagerload(User.branches))
    # for u in q.all():
    #     for c in branches:
    #         print (c.id, c.name,(c in u.branches))

    q = db.session.query(user_branch_map).join(Branch).join(User).all()
    print(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

db.session.query(User.id,User.full_name,Branch.id ,Branch.name).filter(             user_branch_map.c.user_id == User.id).filter(user_branch_map.c.branch_id == Branch.id)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the branches per user, so something like `username, branchname` should allow you to extend it from there. If you define the User model as

```py
class User(db.Model):
  ...
  branches = db.relationship("Branch", secondary=user_branch_map, backref="users")
  ...
```

then you just need to join `User` to `Branch`, and SQLAlchemy will do the rest:

```py
q = q = db.session.query(User.username, Branch.branch_name).select_from(User).join(user_branch_map).join(Branch).all()
```

That should generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT user.username, branch.branch_name
FROM user
JOIN user_branch_map ON user.id = user_id
JOIN branch ON branch.id = branch_id
```

And using `backref="users"` should then also make a `users` attribute on `Branch` available (see the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html))

Comment: **I am getting this error**   
`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <class 'app.Branch'>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit 
left side, as well as providing an explcit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.`

Comment: **Although i am getting my result by doing this**                                              


`maptable = db.session.query(User.id,User.full_name,Branch.id ,Branch.name).filter(
            user_branch_map.c.user_id == User.id).filter(user_branch_map.c.branch_id == Branch.id)`

Comment: So you're not using the `.join()` I noted in my answer? Do you have a reason why?

Comment: I have tried your method and i was getting the above error.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. As the error said, you should add `.select_from()`. `q = db.session.query(User.username, Branch.branch_name).select_from(User).join(Branch).all()`, does that work?

Comment: _I am still getting the same error ._ 
**the method i have mentioned above works , is that valid ?**

Comment: Yes, that is also valid. Do you want to attempt to get the other solution working or is that enough for you? If so, did you change the definition of `User.branches`?

Comment: I have changed the definition as per your solution but that didn't worked out unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219070/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-gerald-schwarz).